# SQL Query dependency diagram / SQL Query visualization in Python

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I write a lot of complicated queries for my job every day. While creating ER diagrams are a lot of fun, I was wondering if anyone has figured out a faster way to create Entity relationship diagram / SQL Query visualization diagram using Python where a SQL query is the input.

Using query in snowflake to create a view so trying to figure out a good way to document it.

Yes, http://queryviz.com/ is a good option but it is unable to handle the level of complexity plus not in python.

Comment: Not Python, but I really like https://www.quickdatabasediagrams.com/ for creating relatively simple diagrams.

Comment: @Ben Good suggestion if I had to define database design but not useful when I input the query. Just tried doesn't work as expected.